# Wordpress *get_current_user_id* returns 0 on remote server but not local server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Please I am working with WordPress and using Ajax to store some data into the database after i have retrieved the logged in user ID with wp function *get_current_user_id()* .

Everything works perfectly fine on my local server - localhost but on my remote server *get_current_user_id()* always return 0 instead of the logged-in user ID.

When i run the submit.php file directly *get_current_user_id()* returns the user ID fine

Please note that the submit.php and Ajax  is not part of Wordpress, it is in a seperate folder within the wordpress root folder

When i run the submit.php file seperately and test to see the resulting executing query the *get_current_user_id()* outputs the correct logged in user id and not 0

*submit.php*

```
require_once("../../../wp-blog-header.php");

$connection = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", 
"db"); // Establishing Connection with Server..
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "db"); // Selecting Database
//Fetching Values from URL
@$score = $_POST['score'];

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
//Insert query
$query = "update gamestats set bestscore = {$score} WHERE game='2048' AND 
playerid = {$user_id} and bestscore <= {$score}";
mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) <= 0){
$ins_query = "INSERT INTO gamestats (bestscore, game, playerid) 
VALUES({$score}, '2048', {$user_id})";
mysqli_query($connection, $ins_query);
}
mysqli_close($connection); // Connection Closed
```

*Ajax Call* file is within same folder as the submit.php

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            //alert(score + " :Post Best Score");
        }
});
```

The initiating code within WP template

```
<iframe height="1057" scrolling="no" align="middle" frameborder="0" src="http://www.xxxx.com/wp-folder/custom-folder/index.html">
```

The iframe is what initiate the whole process which i put with the WP Template.

It is within the index.html that the Ajax script is called

The "custom-folder" is my own custom folder placed within WordPress folder

*NOTE:* *get_current_user_id()* returns the correct user id on local server and everything works perfectly fine but on remote server it returns 0 storing 0 as the playerid into the DB all the time. What could be the problem please help?

Comment: why aren't you using the wordpress ajax hooks?

Comment: @madalin I dont how to do that. Also, the ajax file is not part of WordPress, all it does is to save some data into database which include the user id coming from wp. However, it works fine on my localhost. Thanks

Comment: are you sure you are logged in?

Comment: 100% sure. I even run the script - submit.php and the current user id is properly retrieved but in the Ajax call it returns 0

Comment: Trying to figure out if this problem is about the function get_current_user_id I decided to save the retrieved current_user_id into a cookie from within wp to retrieve within the submit.php page but still has the same issue, stores 0 in db. I am guessing is it something with wp security, perhaps htaccess permission or so?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by clearing cache of the web browser and local storage.